# How to set buttons in Android?

Tags: android

I have 7 to 8 buttons in my application.

Like this.
[image]

How can I do this?
I used:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.searchdialog_layout);

ll.setOrientation(0);

Button btn = new Button(context);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_layout));

btn.setPadding(4,0, 4, 0);

btn.setTextSize(14);

btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

btn.setText("bubble" + " x");

ll.addView(btn) ;
```

But it didn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Define "didn't work". If you are not going to tell us what you think went wrong, we cannot help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button btnabout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
    btnabout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) 
        {
            //do something
        }//end onClick          
    });//end button
```

traditional way of creating a button